# How do I call all instance methods of a class wIth names starting with a given string?

Tags: ruby, dynamic, methods, metaprogramming

I have a simple validation class:

```
class MappingValidator

    def validate(mapping)

    end

    protected

    def validate_presence_of_title(mapping)
      ...
    end

    def validate_presence_of_key(mapping)
      ...
    end

    def validates_class_exists(mapping)
      ...
    end

  end
```

In the `validate` method I would like to call any method starting with `validate_` and pass `mapping` as the parameter. This needs to work for subclasses of `MappingValidator` too, so that if a subclass declares a method starting with `validate_` it will also be called when validate is called on a subclass instance. Order of calls is irrelevant.

Comment: any reason why you dont just include [`ActiveModel::Validations`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html)

Comment: @firien I'm not using Rails and this is a very specific use-case.

Comment: you dont need rails, just the `active_model` gem, although i think that depends on `active_support` (which might be an overkill)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How is this ?

```
class MappingValidator

    def validate(mapping)
       self.methods.grep(/^validate_/).each do |m|
         send(m,mapping)
       end
    end

    protected

    def validate_presence_of_title(mapping)
      p "1"
    end

    def validate_presence_of_key(mapping)
      p "2"
    end

    def validates_class_exists(mapping)
      p "3"
    end

end

MappingValidator.new.validate("validate_")
# >> "1"
# >> "2"
```

Answer (score 3):

Should be as simple as:

```
methods.filter {|m| m.to_s.start_with? 'validate_'}.each {|m| send m, mapping}
```

Comment: I'd probably  use `methods(false)` or `methods - Object.methods` to remove ancestors and/or Object's methods.

Comment: @theTinMan But OP said,he/she want to access from the subclass to superclass,if any. So why `false` ?